# login sql server 2005 on vb6

Tags: sql-server, vb6

can anyone help me how to make the connection in the sub login to be usable by the sub consultationlistviewsource? I know I need a variable but overall I board not SUCCESSFUL. i got always an error "Invalid permission specification" on the line of the sub cn.Open ConsultationListviewSource.
sorry for my bad english

```
Option Explicit

Private cn As ADODB.Connection
Private record As ADODB.Recordset
Private list As ListItem

Public Sub ConsultationListviewSource(ByRef objlistview As Object, ByVal          table As String)

cn.Open
record.Open "SELECT *  FROM [" & table & "]", cn, adOpenDynamic,   adLockOptimistic

If record.Fields.Count = 5 Then
    For k = 0 To 4
        With objlistview.ColumnHeaders
            .Add , , record.Fields(k).Name, objlistview.Width / 2
        End With
    Next k

    record.MoveFirst
    While record.EOF = False
        Set list = objlistview.ListItems.Add(, , record.Fields(0))
        list.SubItems(1) = record.Fields(1)
        list.SubItems(2) = record.Fields(2)
        list.SubItems(3) = record.Fields(3)
        list.SubItems(4) = record.Fields(4)
        record.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
record.Close
End Sub

Sub login(textusername As Variant, textpassword As Variant)
On Error GoTo erreur
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set record = New ADODB.Recordset
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data     Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=bdd_trigger_salarie;User    ID=textusername;Password=textpassword"
cn.Open
MsgBox "bienvenue", vbInformation, "Login"
Exit Sub
erreur:
If Err.Number = -2147217843 Then
    MsgBox "nom d'utilisateur et/ou mot de passe incorrect", vbInformation,   "Login"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set record = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot a lot about VB6 so cannot be 100% sure, but I see one problem in you code: you opened the connection in `Sub Login`, did not close it, and tried to open it in `Sub ConsultationListviewSource` again. The quick fix will be removing the `cn.Open` line in the `ConsultationListviewSource` sub.

But it is not best practice. You should try to minimize the time the connection is opened and close the connection immediately after use.